# MSAccess SQL 0 Count Lines not displayed as 0

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following SQL query in access to report the count of row for a particular week. This issue i have is if there are 0 rows for a particular week instead of reporting 0 it is not reporting anything.

```
TRANSFORM Count(StockChange.StockChangeID) AS CountOfStockChangeID 
SELECT '' AS TransType 
From StockChange 
WHERE (((StockChange.BasePart) Like '*::*') AND ((StockChange.TransDate)>=#1/1/2013# And (StockChange.TransDate)<(Date())-(Weekday(Date())-1)) AND ((StockChange.Notes) Like '*dispos*')) 
Group BY '' 
ORDER BY Format([transdate],'ww')+1-1 DESC 
PIVOT Format([transdate],'ww')+1-1;"
```

I have looked everywhere for an answer but im beginning to thing it not possible without writing some code.

Comment: Have you tried Count(Sum(1)) instead of Count(StockChange.StockChangeID)?

Comment: I get 'Cannot have aggregate function in expression (Count(Sum(1)))'

Comment: One way is to define the column headers. Based on concept shown in example for monthly report http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/query/crosstab-report/index.html